# Can I limit the amps drawn by a charging battery

Tags: automotive, 12v

I want to connect two 12V car batteries. A part of the connection is limited to 15A (cigarette lighter). Is it possible to limit the amps on the wire so I can safely connect the batteries via the 15A fuse & 1mm^2 wire?

Comment: yes it is possible.  many ways to do it. Can you build stuff?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I can build lego sets, so I should be fine. What is in your mind?

Comment: easiest is this https://www.mouser.ca/Circuit-Protection/Thermistors/Resettable-Fuses-PPTC/_/N-axfyt?P=1z0z63xZ1z0x5uy  you may want to juggle trip and hold current by getting several >4A ratings in parallel  so trip at 15 A and hold at 8

Comment: Chris, you want to allow two batteries to "equilibrate"? Discharging one to charge the other, but limiting the current of that process? Would a car be running while tapping off the cigarette lighter socket?

Comment: @jonk, correct. However, I just saw that the second battery (the one I want to connect to the cigarette lighter for charging) has 10A max charging current stated in it's spec sheet. Does this mean that it will not draw more than that anyways. So I can connect it directly?

Comment: @Chris No. It does NOT mean that. If you connect them directly, it will be dangerous and you will likely blow the fuse (hopefully, anyway.) I think you should want to have an appropriate electronic circuit mediating this transfer. There are battery chargers already designed and being sold as products which operate from the cigarette lighter socket. Is there a reason you want to avoid these?

Comment: @jonk No, I am not opposed to such a solution. I could only find devices that are used to charge the car battery via the cigarette socket, but none that are intended to charge a secondary battery from the car battery via the socket. I am not sure what to search for.

Comment: @Chris I'm still not sure if the car is running while this is taking place. It might matter. A car running will probably have a somewhat higher running voltage than a car battery alone and this can be used with a simpler circuit. If the car is not running then it may require a so-called *switcher* arrangement. More complicated. At that point, might be better off getting a low-wattage AC mains inverter (100-150 W?) and using a trickle-charger from there.

Comment: @jonk I would only use it when the car/alternator is running

Comment: @Chris Ok. That sounds easier. But now that I look, I think I see the difficulty you are having finding something commercial. In the IC world, there are devices such as [this one](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX34565-50230.pdf), which might offer an easy DIY. Haven't looked closely at that datasheet, though. But something like that, anyway.

Comment: Chris if that battery is an SLA are you aware also of the Vbat Min and Max voltage?  Your vehicle should be 14.2V max. You may need a smart battery manager. Define your battery model

Answer (score 1):

A simple rheostat can control the voltage, but remember, resistance =heat so be sure you are not exceeding the limits of the rheostat and mount it securely in an area that is not heat sensitive (I.E. near plastics) and solder and insulate all connections.

Comment: Rheostats limit current.